# How to validate start date and end date in angular?

Tags: angular, validation, date

I am building component in angular in which I want start date to be greater than end date. I am wondering what changes I need to make in my HTML and TS codes to get it done. The snippets of HTML and TS codes which I am using are:

HTML:

```
<form class="unavailability-form" [formGroup]="unavailabilityForm" *ngIf="loaded">
<div class="component-title" matDialogTitle>
   {{'PORTAL.TEXTUNAVAILABILITY' | translate}}
</div>
<mat-toolbar>
   <div class="container"
      fxLayout="row"
      fxLayout.xs="column"
      fxLayoutGap.xs="0">
      <div>
         <h1>{{componentTitle}}</h1>
      </div>
   </div>
</mat-toolbar>
<mat-dialog-content>
   <div class="container" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutGap.xs="0" fxLayoutGap="10px">
      <div class="item item-1" fxFlex="50%" fxFlexOrder="1">
         <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="{{'PORTALSTARTDATE' | translate}}"  type="text" formControlName="startDate" [(ngModel)]="availability.startDate" [readonly]="!componentPermission.writePermission">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
         </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div class="item item-2" fxFlex="50%" fxFlexOrder="1">
         <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="{{'PORTAL.ENDDATE' | translate}}"  type="text" formControlName="endDate" [(ngModel)]="availability.endDate" [readonly]="!componentPermission.writePermission">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
         </mat-form-field>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item item-1" fxFlex="50%" fxFlexOrder="1">
      <mat-form-field>
         <input matInput placeholder="{{'PORTAL.UNAVAILABILITYREASON' | translate}}" type="text" formControlName="unavailabilityReason" [(ngModel)]="availability.unavailabilityReason" [readonly]="!componentPermission.writePermission">
      </mat-form-field>
   </div>
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions>
   <div class="container" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutGap.xs="0">
      <div class="item item-1" fxFlex="100%">
         <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="!locationForm.valid || !componentPermission.writePermission" (click)="onSave()">{{'PORTAL.CONFIRM' | translate}}</button>
         <button mat-raised-button [matDialogClose]="canceled" color="primary">{{'PORTAL.CANCEL' | translate}}</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</mat-dialog-actions>
</form>
```

TS:

```
  validateForm() {
    this.unavailabilityForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'startDate': [''],
      'endDate': [''],
      'unavailabilityReason': ['']
    });
  }
```

In the above code, {{PORTAL.___}} text refers to the value from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that you cannot use `ngModel` within your form. You have to feed form from your component with data. Here is form with removed `ngModel`:

```
<mat-dialog-content>
   <form [formGroup]="unavailabilityForm " novalidate fxFlex>
      <div class="container" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutGap.xs="0" fxLayoutGap="10px">
         <div class="item item-1" fxFlex="50%" fxFlexOrder="1">
            <mat-form-field>
               <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="{{'PORTALSTARTDATE' | translate}}"  type="text" formControlName="startDate" [readonly]="!componentPermission.writePermission">
               <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
               <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
            </mat-form-field>
         </div>
         <div class="item item-2" fxFlex="50%" fxFlexOrder="1">
            <mat-form-field>
               <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="{{'PORTAL.ENDDATE' | translate}}"  type="text" formControlName="endDate" [readonly]="!componentPermission.writePermission">
               <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
               <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
            </mat-form-field>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item item-1" fxFlex="50%" fxFlexOrder="1">
         <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="{{'PORTAL.UNAVAILABILITYREASON' | translate}}" type="text" formControlName="unavailabilityReason"  [readonly]="!componentPermission.writePermission">
         </mat-form-field>
      </div>
   </form>
</mat-dialog-content>
```

Then you need to initialize form and add FormGroup level validator to your group. Also I feed data to your form:

```
initForm() {
    this.unavailabilityForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'startDate': [availability.startDate],
      'endDate': [availability.endDate],
      'unavailabilityReason': [availability.unavailabilityReason]
    }, validateDate);
  }
```

Your custom validator function in `FormGroup` will be `validateDate`.

Custom validator function should be like this:

```
function validateDate(group: FormGroup) {
  ///TODO: Implement some better validation logic
  const invalid = group.get('startDate').value > group.get('endDate').value;

  ///TODO: Implement some logic to mark controls dirty if is necessary.

  return invalid ? { 'invalidDate': true } : null;
}
```

In custom validator on `FormGroup` level you can you can access to all controls form that group and perform validation. Please note that value of your form will be string so, if you are working with `Date` you will need better logic to compare dates.

Also please not that group level validator maybe will not display validation feedback, so you will need manually to mark controls to be dirty if is necessary.

Comment: You cannot combine `ngModel` and `formControlName`. I mean you cannot have `ngModel` within `FormGroup`. Which concrete issues you have? You have to use `formControlName` for data binding with HTML controls.

Comment: Here I am using ngModel for binding the data from the typescript. Is it wrong ?

Comment: Yes, it is wrong. You are using model driven forms. It means your model will drive form and form will update HTML. You need to implement that. See update.

Answer (score 0):

With reactive forms, here is how i do it.

```
  deploymentSignOffDatesValidator(g: FormGroup) {
      return g.get('dateOfSignOff').value > g.get('dateOfDeployment').value ? null : {'unsequencial': true};
    }

  createEditUserForm(item: SaveUser) {
    if (!item) {
      item = {
        dateOfDeployment: '',
        dateOfSignOff: '',
      }
    }
this.userEditForm = this.fb.group({
      dateOfDeployment: [item.dateOfDeployment, Validators.required],
      dateOfSignOff: [item.dateOfSignOff]
    }, {validator: this.deploymentSignOffDatesValidator});

<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12">
                                <fieldset class="form-group">
                                    <label for="dateOfSignOff">Date of SignOff:</label>
                                    <input
                                        class="form-control"
                                        placeholder="Date of SignOff"
                                        bsDatepicker
                                        formControlName="dateOfSignOff"
                                        [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD', containerClass: 'theme-dark-blue' }"
                                        [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': userEditForm.get('dateOfSignOff').errors && (formDir.submitted || userEditForm.get('dateOfSignOff').touched) || userEditForm.hasError('unsequencial') && userEditForm.get('dateOfSignOff').touched}">
                                        <div class="" *ngIf="userEditForm.hasError('unsequencial') && userEditForm.get('dateOfSignOff').touched">The Deploymnet Date must be less than Sign Off Date</div>
                                </fieldset>                                
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check out my library ng-swiss-army-knife which has this form validator inside (and many other useful javascript/typescript/angular stuff)
https://github.com/nickwinger/ng-swiss-army-knife

Comment: Please describe the resolution in more detail with more insights like explaining the actual reason, add you working code snippet and steps to perform to eradicate the issues.
For more details visit StackOverflow's guidelines.

Comment: Here is the source code: https://github.com/nickwinger/ng-swiss-army-knife/blob/master/projects/ng-swiss-army-knife/src/lib/validators.ts

Comment: And here you find how to use it: https://github.com/nickwinger/ng-swiss-army-knife/blob/master/README.md